# Blank screen boot loop on SM-T211

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung, boot-loop, samsung-kies, unrooting

I have a Samsung SM-T211 (India) tablet and am using it for 2 years. I have rooted it using ODIN and TWRP (android 4.4.2) based on online tutorials and it is working fine. Couple of days back when I connected to samsung Kies, it showed that there is an update. I have read in internet that updating through Kies only makes your OS updated resulting an unrooted device which I thought is OK.

Kies downloaded the program and installed on the TAB. It said the TAB would reboot after install. The TAB didn't booted to samsung logo instead entered a blank screen boot loop(I can see a dim light on screen).It is rebooting itself into blank screen. I have tried to enter DOWNLOAD mode but no key configuration is working. The TAB is not even connecting to PC. I have reinstalled Kies and USB drivers still no luck with detection.

Its been a week and I have observed the following :

a) Some times it completely shuts off only enters boot loop when connected to wall charger

b) couple of times when tried to enter download mode, a blank screen with four lines showing ODIN, OS- CUSTOM appeared. It only happened twice randomly and I couldn't capture the image.

I also removed and reattached the battery connector according to  some tutorials with no result.

I have given it to samsung customer care, they said there is a display problem which I don't believe as it is flawlessly working for over two years and I can see OS status as custom briefly (as mentioned above)

I am pretty naive to android(and its terminology) and cannot come with own solution however I can follow any guidelines if given.

Please provide me your suggestions to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.